# Button styling with 28.0.0-rc01

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have the following button:

```
 <Button                                    
     android:id="@+id/addexperience_button"                                    
     style="@style/MyButton"                                    
     android:layout_width="match_parent"                                    
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                    
     android:layout_alignLeft="@id/emptystate_image"                                    
     android:layout_alignRight="@id/emptystate_image"                                    
     android:layout_below="@id/emptystate_image"                                    
     android:text="@string/pickdetail_addexperience" />
```

with this styling:

```
  <style name="MyButton" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/single_spacing</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/single_spacing</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_primarybutton</item>
    </style>
```

bg_primarybutton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="6dp"
    android:insetLeft="4dp"
    android:insetRight="4dp"
    android:insetTop="6dp">
    <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary">
                <corners android:radius="18dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

Now this button looks like this with `28.0.0-alpha1`:

[image]

But looks like this with `alpha2`, `alpha3` and `rc01`:

[image]

How come its ignoring my styling on a later version (esp. a RC?) Maybe there is something fundamentally wrong on my Button definition?

Comment: 28.0.0-rc1 of what ? Appcompat or design-support ? What is the parent of AppTheme ?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: as for the version, both design and appcompat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is because of your `AppTheme` being `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`, the inflater of your activity is inflating a [`MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) instead of a `Button` and you can't change the background of a `MaterialButton` the same way of an old `Button` (see doc) .

If you want to have the same style as before, replace your `MyButton` style with

```
<style name="MyButton">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/single_spacing</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/single_spacing</item>
  <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="cornerRadius">18dp</item>
  <item name="rippleColor">?android:attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
</style>
```

Note that you should not extend your `AppTheme` when writing a style (that will be used in the `style="@style/MyStyle` attribute) for a View.

They introduced the auto inflation of `MaterialButton` with the alpha2.
Open the class `android.support.design.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater` on alpha1 and alpha2 to see the difference.

If you DO NOT want this behavior of auto inflating `MaterialButton` change your `AppTheme`to be

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

Comment: saved my life, for some reason it also works if i use AppCompatButton.

Comment: One more thing, can you expand on this: "Note that you should not extend your AppTheme when writing a style (that will be used in the style="@style/MyStyle attribute) for a View." Why is that?